# Не запускается webpack

Tags: webpack

Консоль пишет ошибку при запуске webpack.

```
script.js:1 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './src/main.js'
    at webpackMissingModule (script.js:1:26)
    at script.js:1:36
    at bundle.js:41:12
```

Будто он файл не видит. Не совсем понимаю что не так с файлом. Webpack не ставится толком и не запускается. Может кто подсказать в чем проблема?

Код main.js

```
let two = 2;

export {two};
 
export function sayHi() {
    console.log('Hello');
}
```

Код script.js

```
import {one, two} from '.src/main.js';

console.log(`${one} and ${two}`);
```

Ну и сам bundle.js

```
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    var __webpack_modules__ = ({});
/************************************************************************/
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var __webpack_module_cache__ = {};
/******/    
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        var cachedModule = __webpack_module_cache__[moduleId];
/******/        if (cachedModule !== undefined) {
/******/            return cachedModule.exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = __webpack_module_cache__[moduleId] = {
/******/            // no module.id needed
/******/            // no module.loaded needed
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/    
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        __webpack_modules__[moduleId](module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/    
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/    
/************************************************************************/
var __webpack_exports__ = {};
/*!**********************!*\
  !*** ./js/script.js ***!
  \**********************/
const myModule = __webpack_require__(Object(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module './src/main.js'"); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }())); 

const myModuleInstance = new myModule();

myModuleInstance.hello();
myModuleInstance.goodbye();

 
/******/ })()
;
```

Ну и HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    

    <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Файл Main лежит по адресу

```
папка\src\main.js
```

Файл script.js лежит в

```
папка\src\js\script.js
```

Файл Index лежит

```
папка\index.html
```

Bundle лежит

```
папка\dist\bundle.js
```

Comment: Так .src/main.js или все же ./src/main.js?

Comment: Что .src/main.js, что ./src/main.js, ошибка одинаковая выдается, меняется только "./src".

Comment: Задам вопрос иначе: где лежит script.js по отношению к main.js? Где лежит сам main.js? Покажите структуру расположения в вопросе с помощью "править".

Comment: Добавил. Посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Итак, после вашего последнего комментария видно, что у вас ошибка в относительных путях. Для `\src\js\script.js`, расположение `\src\main.js` должно быть указано как `../main.js`, а не `./src/main.js`

**UPD** (чтобы в комментариях не писать, а то непонятки какие-то).
Итак (код неоптимальный специально, чтобы сравнивать с оригиналом автора):

Файл `/src/main.mjs`

```js
function one() {
    console.log('Hello');
}

let two = 2;

export { one };
export { two };
```

Файл `/src/js/script.mjs`

```js
import { one, two } from '../main.mjs';

one();
console.log(`${two}`);
```

Comment: везде поставил " ./main.js ", но проблема не ушла.

Comment: Две точки, две - ../main.js

Comment: все равно та же ошибка " Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../main.js'
    at webpackMissingModule (script.js:1:26)
    at script.js:1:26
    at bundle.js:41:12 "

Comment: Я надеюсь, вы исправили import {one, two} from '.src/main.js'; на import {one, two} from '../main';

Comment: Да, я в каждом файле (bundle - 3 шт., script) ч/з поиск исправил этот момент. В чем еще может быть причина?

Comment: Так. Везде - это неправильно. Файлы из "везде" лежат не так же относительно main.js, как и script.js, это понятно? Для начала смените в script.js строку import {one, two} from '.src/main.js'; на import {one, two} from '../main'; - именно скопируйте отсюда.

Comment: Везде, где упоминалось ./main.js, я исправил на ../main.js

Comment: Везде - это не ответ. Во-первых, не ./main.js (это вы уже "исправили" в одной неправильной точкой). Я в предыдущем комментарии попросил исправить в script.js строку import {one, two} from '.src/main.js'; на import {one, two} from '../main'; - только здесь и читайте внимательно: я просил скопировать - там  '../main'; а вы опять ../main.js - читаете невнимательно, это как минимум. Я у себя пересоздал и у меня работает (у вас там косяки с export one, но эта проблема вам высветится позже - не имеет отношения к путям)

Comment: можете Вашу почту написать, я бы Вам отправил сборку. Я и так правлю и так, все равно та же ошибка.

Comment: Нет, так не делается. Я добавил в ответ пример. Эта ваша сборка - пока что примитивный учебный проект. Учитывая тот факт, что у вас вообще пока что пробел с относительными путями (а это очень банальная вещь), то я советую вам немного еще по теории пройтись. Я не сторонник особо видео-курсов, но я вижу, что базовые понятие у вас есть. Советую просмотреть https://youtu.be/CxgOKJh4zWE - найдите раздел импорта и экспорта по таймкоду. Этот парень расставит точки над i.

Comment: ... и еще, на всякий случай: для /dist/bundle.js путь до main.js будет  '../src/main.js', если что. Я просто не знаю, что там у вас еще в сборке, но любой IDE будем вам подсказывать относительные пути (даже VS Code)

Answer (score 0):

В общем было несколько проблем: 1) надо вебпак запускать в общем папке ч/з консоль (ГитБаш). 2) webpack.config.js засунуть в общую папку